# Universities offering courses about Drones (Unmanned Aerial Vehicles [UAVs])

Tags: mobile-robot, uav, research, drone

I am trying to gather some information about university courses offered about drones (or Unmanned Aerial Vehicles).

At the beginning, I thought that I would have found way more than what I found and instead I could notice that most of the universities do not offer courses directly about drones (or aerial robotics) but more about mobile robotics (which of course include drones).
Some of the universities I have seen that are offering these kinds of courses are listed below (it might be useful for someone else in the same situation). However, I would like to know if you know of more of these courses.

1. [Upenn (Coursera) - Aerial Robotics](https://www.coursera.org/learn/robotics-flight)
2. [University of Nevada Reno - Introduction to Aerial Robotics](http://www.kostasalexis.com/introduction-to-aerial-robotics.html)
3. [Swiss Federal Institue of Technology (EPFL) - Aerial Robotics](https://moodle.epfl.ch/enrol/index.php?id=15799)

Somehow related:

1. [Politecnico di Milano - Aeronautical Systems-Guidance and Control](https://www.mathworks.com/academia/courseware/aeronautical-systems-guidance-and-control.html)

If I will find more of them I will try to add them to this post.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: The Udacity [Flying Car and Autonomous Flight Engineer](https://www.udacity.com/course/flying-car-nanodegree--nd787) "nanodegree" may also have the sort of thing you're looking for, although I don't think the course is associated with a particular traditional university.

Comment: Welcome to *Robotics* desmond13, but I'm afraid that *Life Questions* are off-topic. Choosing how to spend your time (books to read, classes to take, projects to construct, career to pursue etc.) may be difficult, but it's specific to you, so unlikely to help future visitors. Questions like this are welcome in [chat] when you have the [privilege](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/chat). We prefer *[practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask)*, see [ask] & [about].

Comment: Aerobatics or drone flight in general is just a want to physically demonstrate controls. What you **should** be looking for are "trajectory control" classes - try searching `"trajectory control" classes "edu"`. Be aware, though, that trajectory control is like the tip of an educational pyramid - you'll also need classes in optimization, controls, kinematics, dynamics, etc. etc.

Answer (score 1):

You should probably check out the universities below. I have read about some great research work done in the field of Aerial Robotics in these universities. They might not have a separate program as such for Aerial Robotics but there's extensive amount of projects that several students and researchers take part in under this area, be it through the Mechanical or Electrical side.

1. Queensland University of Technology
2. National University of Singapore
3. ETH Zurich

Hope this helps you out!